# groupby issue on dates surrounding values : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by

I want to calculate the differences between cells in a dataframe of one column.

```
> head(df_benchmark)
        Date .STOXXR
1 2000-01-03  478.52
2 2000-01-04  459.53
3 2000-01-05  448.19
4 2000-01-06  446.24
5 2000-01-07  455.80
6 2000-01-10  462.97
```

The data file is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MExW-r0NNGAlMxlQh_tjOscpm6xBiMsfMKRPQykJgr8/edit?usp=sharing).

So I tried the following :

```
df_benchmark <- read.xlsx("Data.xlsx", sheet = "Benchmark", startRow = 2,colNames = TRUE, detectDates = TRUE, skipEmptyRows = FALSE)
df_benchmark[2] <- data.matrix(df_benchmark[2])

> library(lubridate)
> percent_change2 <- function(x)last(x)/first(x) - 1
> monthly_return_benchmark <- df_benchmark %>% 
+   group_by(gr = floor_date(Date, unit = "month")) %>%
+   summarize_at(vars(-Date, -gr), percent_change2) %>%
+   ungroup() %>%
+   select(-gr) %>% 
+   as.matrix()
```

Yet I have an error. It seems that my dataframe with a column of dates and a column of values must be a 1d atomic vector or list. It seems the reason is a problem of variables :

```
Error: Each variable must be a 1d atomic vector or list.
Problem variables: '.STOXXR'
```

## Update

I tried [Julian_Hn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55401086/4764604) who noticed that I used `df_benchmark[2] <- data.matrix(df_benchmark[2])`. This was used because I had a format issue.

So I tried the following code:

```
library(xts)
df_benchmark <- read.xlsx("Data.xlsx", sheet = "Benchmark", startRow = 2,colNames = TRUE, detectDates = TRUE, skipEmptyRows = FALSE)

percent_change2 <- function(x) last(x)/first(x) - 1
monthly_return_benchmark <- df_benchmark %>% 
  group_by(gr = floor_date(as_date(Date), unit = "month")) %>%
  summarize_at(vars(-Date, -gr), percent_change2) %>%
  ungroup()

# Generamos el xts, indicando la columna con la info de tiempo
monthly_return_benchmark <- xts(monthly_return[,-1], order.by=monthly_return$gr)
```

But I had the following error:

```
> library(xts)
> df_benchmark <- read.xlsx("Data.xlsx", sheet = "Benchmark", startRow = 2,colNames = TRUE, detectDates = TRUE, skipEmptyRows = FALSE)
> 
> percent_change2 <- function(x) last(x)/first(x) - 1
> monthly_return_benchmark <- df_benchmark %>% 
+   group_by(gr = floor_date(as_date(Date), unit = "month")) %>%
+   summarize_at(vars(-Date, -gr), percent_change2) %>%
+   ungroup()
Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

## Third attempt

Only by using the `group_by` using the months as units do I get the following:

```
> monthly_return_benchmark <- df_benchmark %>% 
+     group_by(gr = floor_date(Date, unit = "month"))
> monthly_return_benchmark
Source: local data frame [4,604 x 3]
Groups: gr [216]

         Date .STOXXR         gr
       <date>   <chr>     <date>
1  2000-01-03  478.52 2000-01-01
2  2000-01-04  459.53 2000-01-01
3  2000-01-05  448.19 2000-01-01
4  2000-01-06  446.24 2000-01-01
5  2000-01-07   455.8 2000-01-01
6  2000-01-10  462.97 2000-01-01
7  2000-01-11  459.85 2000-01-01
8  2000-01-12  459.84 2000-01-01
9  2000-01-13  462.27 2000-01-01
10 2000-01-14  473.43 2000-01-01
# ... with 4,594 more rows
```

Now I have to do the `percent_change2` but it never worked.

Answer (score 0):

I've spotted a few mistakes:
First: why do you do this step? `df_benchmark[2] <- data.matrix(df_benchmark[2])` This is the cause for the Error you've shown.
After I fixed this, I found another error in the pipeline.

This code now runs for me:

```
library(xts)
df_benchmark <- read.xlsx("Data.xlsx", sheet = "Benchmark", startRow = 2,colNames = TRUE, detectDates = TRUE, skipEmptyRows = FALSE)

percent_change2 <- function(x) last(x)/first(x) - 1
monthly_return_benchmark <- df_benchmark %>% 
  group_by(gr = floor_date(as_date(Date), unit = "month")) %>%
  summarize_at(vars(-Date, -gr), percent_change2) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I did `df_benchmark[2]<-data.matrix(df_benchmark[2])` because I inspired myself of the same function I did for the other sheet with all the stocks. Yet I have an error with your code : `Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) :   non-numeric argument to binary operator`